# Uber API getting 404 on /partners/trips, how to get more insights

Tags: uber-api

We are Uber partners and currently developing a platform for our members.

From Uber Developer Dashboard - Analytics we are receiving errors 404 & 500, in the API docs there are no corresponding details for this errors.

I know that in general the errors correspond with:

- `500 - server error (Uber side)`
- `404 - not found (Uber side)`

Does anybody knows how to get more insights on this errors, like what triggered them, what we should change or integrate?

Or from the developer dashboard what we should set?

[Screenshot of today errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRG0R.png)

Comment: What is your client ID? 404 means the trip ID may be incorrect. Also, this is likely something better handled by following up with uber directly on their API support google forum.

Comment: @KyleDavis thank you for the help. After a detailed investigation we figured out that the user account type wasn't a driver account and the token used for getting trips was an "invalid_grant"

Comment: great! glad you resolved :)